# Verificação/validação em Dart/Flutter no banco de dados Firebase Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firestore

Estou tentando fazer uma verificação/validação em Dart/Flutter no banco de dados Firebase Firestore para não salvar a mesma string numero de série duas vezes no banco, mas estou fazendo algo errado, pois ele continua salvando o mesmo campo e valor mesmo sendo igual.

Código

```
 var numero = Firestore.instance.collection("lockers").document().snapshots();

    if (numero  == "$_numeroSerie"){
      print("QR Code ja cadastrado");
    } else {
      await Firestore.instance
          .collection("lockers")
          .document()
          .setData({"numero_serie": _numeroSerie});
    }
```

Como esta no banco de dados Firebase
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Isto deu certo !

```
    final QuerySnapshot result = await Future.value(Firestore.instance
        .collection("lockers")
        .where("numero_serie", isEqualTo: "$_numeroSerie")
        .limit(1)
        .getDocuments());

    final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = result.documents;
    if (documents.length == 1) {
      confirmacao(context);
    } else {
      await Firestore.instance
          .collection("lockers")
          .document()
          .setData({"numero_serie": _numeroSerie});
    }
  }
```